# Using {} brackets after statement in Java, will this cause problems ever?

Tags: java

I just started learning java ( I come from Javascript and PHP) about two days ago and I am reading my textbook, and noticed that my textbook always has a class of the form say

```
public class BankAccount
{
    private double balance;
    public BankAccount()
    {
        balance = 0;
    }
    // some other code here...
}
```

I.E notice how the brackets are on different lines.

Now lets take a look at something in javascript

```
function getPerson(){
    return
            {
                firstname: 'Tony'
            }

}

console.log(getPerson());
```

Here the Javascript engine says "Hey, since we put those brackets on another line after return I'm just gonna automatically insert a semicolon after return". As a result some of the books ive read on js say to just put the squiggly brackets on the same line to ever avoiding this.  Thus logging `undefined`

**My Question**

Does something like this ever happen in Java? I'm wondering since my book so far just puts the squiggly on different lines, if this automatic semi colon thing could mess me up.

;

Comment: No, Java does not insert any semicolons. (But something/someone inserted a random one at the very end of your post `:)`)

Comment: No, it will not happen with the Java compiler.

Comment: Cool, nice to know!

Comment: Why downvote, I googled this for a while and couldn't find anything about automatic semicolon insertion in java, plus it isnt mentioned in my textbook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java is not like Javascript. In Java, semi-colons at the end of statement are compulsory.
Moreover, Java will **never** add semi-colon automatically for whatever reasons.

Writing:

```
public class BankAccount
{
}
```

or

```
public class BankAccount {
}
```

is just a matter of convention. Both are strictly the same from the parser's point of view. Do what whatever your programming convention tells you to do. Just be consistent within a project.

Same goes for function declaration.

Comment: Great, thats one thing less to worry about in this massive programming language :O

Answer (score 0):

Java does not have semicolon insertion like JavaScript does.
You can split a statement over as many lines as you like, but it must eventually be terminated with a semicolon.

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking if you need to put a `semicolon` after method declarations in `Java` then no, you do not. I cannot think of a case in `Java` where you **do** put `semicolon` after a pair of `{}`.

Comment: You need to do {}; after anonymous inner class definition e.g. in `return new Runnable() {};` the trailing `;` is required.